# Build problems with PostGIS 2.4.4 on MacOS 10.12

Tags: postgis, macports

I'm attempting to build PostGIS 2.4.4, on MacOS 10.12, using MacPorts for the various libraries.  The build is currently failing with (while linking shp2pgsql):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_iconv", referenced from:
     _utf8 in shp2pgsql-core.o
 "_iconv_close", referenced from:
     _utf8 in shp2pgsql-core.o
 "_iconv_open", referenced from:
     _utf8 in shp2pgsql-core.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Some research has revealed that there's an issue with the libiconv that MacPorts installs, and one should use the system library, but I haven't had success using --with-libiconv-prefix and  --with-libiconv pointing at the system library in /usr.  Has anyone done this successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I was insufficiently diligent about trying config options; setting it to explicitly use the MacPorts installed libconv worked:

```
./configure --with-libiconv-prefix=/opt/local --with-libiconv=/opt/local
```

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that MacPorts offers a port of that version of postgis?

```
$ port info postgis2
postgis2 @2.4.4 (databases, gis)
Variants:             comments, gui, [+]postgresql10, postgresql93, postgresql94, postgresql95, postgresql96, proj4, [+]raster, sfcgal, [+]topology, universal

Description:          PostGIS 2 adds geometrical, geographical and topological types, and functions operating thereon, to the PostGreSQL database.     The 2.0 release also provides raster handling and basic 3D geometry capacities
                      (TIN and polyhedra).
Homepage:             http://postgis.refractions.net/

Build Dependencies:   autoconf, automake, libtool, libxslt
Library Dependencies: geos, proj, libiconv, libxml2, json-c, postgresql10, gdal
Conflicts with:       postgis
Platforms:            darwin
License:              GPL-2+
Maintainers:          Email: vince@macports.org
                      Policy: openmaintainer
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you mismatch headers and libraries. E.g. compiling with the iconv headers from `/usr/include` but linking against the iconv library from `/opt/local/lib` will cause this problem.

That's because the iconv headers installed by MacPorts contain a `#define iconv libiconv`, which is the symbol provided by the library. It is not a MacPorts decision to ship this define, btw; it's the upstream default.